# Getting the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error..vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I don't undertand why I'm getting this error, code was working and running perfectly earlier. I was trying to update the user's email via button. It worked fine but now for some reason it keeps giving me the error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Line 34:             EmailTextBox.Text = u.Email"

Been scratching at this for a couple of hours now, anyone have an idea what it might be?

My aspx.vb code is:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim u As MembershipUser

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 u = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        EmailTextBox.Text = u.Email
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub UpdateEmailButton_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs)
    Try
        u.Email = EmailTextBox.Text
    Membership.UpdateUser(u)

    Msg.Text = "User e-mail updated."
Catch e As System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException

    Msg.Text = e.Message
End Try
End Sub
```

aspx code:

```
 <h3>Update E-Mail Address for <%=User.Identity.Name%></h3>

  <asp:Label id="Msg" ForeColor="maroon" runat="server" /><br />

  <table cellpadding="3" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>E-mail Address:</td>
      <td><asp:TextBox id="EmailTextBox" MaxLength="128" Columns="30" runat="server" /></td>
      <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="EmailRequiredValidator" runat="server"
                                    ControlToValidate="EmailTextBox" ForeColor="red"
                                    Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><asp:Button id="UpdateEmailButton" 
                      Text="Update E-mail" 
                      OnClick="UpdateEmailButton_OnClick" 
                      runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need into to the debugging model and see the **u = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name)** whether is null.

i guess the Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name) return null. may be your logged was timeout,may be just MembershipUser occure error.

Comment: Thanks your answer somewhat helped, it was due to the user membership data being displayed before the user logged in, fixed the problem. :)